# didReceiveMessage XMPP not called

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xmpp, xmppframework

I am new to iOS and developing chatting app,
i want to initiate chat between two user, i got my roaster list from server.

I made chatting screen now on click of send button button i want to send text to connected user.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {
                    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
                    [body setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msgId]];

                    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
                    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
                    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"testuser1"];
                    [message addChild:body];

                    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:message];
}
```

After doing this didReceiveMessage is not getting called

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{

    NSLog(@"---------- xmppStream:didReceiveMessage: ----------");

    NSLog(@"--from----%@", [message from]);

 if([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];

        NSLog(@"mmmmmmmmmmssssssgggg-%@",msg);
    }
}
```

**Where i am making mistake?**
***Please help and thanks in advance!!***

Answer (score 0):

You are sending to an invalid JID (Jabber ID).

```
  [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"testuser1"];
```

have to be something like

```
  [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"testuser1@yourservername"];
```

A short [FAQ](https://www.jabber.org/faq.html#jid)

Comment: Not all servers allows to send messages to yourself. However be sure to have correct config (serverName is not serverHost, so 127.0.0.1 will fail most of times) and try to log full message to check what have you created. I don't see "from" and don't know if framework adds itself, just for example

Comment: my server name is localhost